# Cannot get onDrop, onDragEnter or onDragOver to work at all

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, drag-and-drop

I'm having a problem with the dropping part of a custom Drag and Drop. I've been looking at tutorials and Q&A about this all day and it seems my code should be working, but not even close.
Can you see what I'm doing wrong? I've taken it down to the easiest expression and it's still not working (Editor.js is just the testing ground, useDrag.js is the hooks file and ContainerDiv is just a styled div).

File Editor.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import useDrag from '../hooks/useDrag'
import ContainerDiv from '../ui/ContainerDiv'
 
const Editor = (props) => {

    const {handleDragStart, handleDragEnd, handleDragEnter, handleDragOver, handleDrop} = useDrag()
 
    return(
 
        <ContainerDiv
            height = '300px'
        >

            <ContainerDiv
                bgcolor = '#DE3636'
                width = '100px'
                height = '100px'
                onDragEnter = {handleDragEnter}
                onDragOver = {handleDragOver}
                onDrop = {handleDrop}
            />

            <ContainerDiv
                bgcolor = '#3651DE'
                width = '100px'
                height = '100px'
                draggable
                onDragStart = {handleDragStart}
                onDragEnd = {handleDragEnd}  
            />  

        </ContainerDiv>  
 
    )
}
```

File useDrag.js

```
const useDrag = () => {

    const handleDragStart = () => {
        console.log('Started dragging')
    }

    const handleDragEnd = () => {
        console.log('Finished dragging')
    }

    const handleDragEnter = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        e.stopPropagation()
        console.log('Entered dropzone')
    }

    const handleDragOver = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        e.stopPropagation()
        console.log('Dragged over')
    }

    const handleDrop = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        e.stopPropagation()
        console.log('Dropped')
    }

    return {
        handleDragStart,
        handleDragEnd,
        handleDragEnter,
        handleDragOver,
        handleDrop,
    }

}

export default useDrag
```

'Started dragging' and 'Finished dragging' are being printed just fine, so the events onDragStart and onDragEnd are working, but onDrop, onDragOver and onDragEnter are not printing anything at all, so they are not being fired.
Can you see directly what the problem is here?

Best

---

EDIT1: Problem solved, and what a waste of time! There was no prroblem with my code, it turns out drop events do not fire in dev mode in Chrome, which is where I was testing. By some coincidence I realized it was working outside of dev mode, go figure. Does anybody know if this might be a problem affecting just me at the moment or is this a known bug? I can confirm that I just restarted everything and drop events are still not firing under chrome dev. I'm on Chrome Version 88.0.4324.96 (Official Build) (x86_64)

EDIT2: Upon further review of this problem, I can confirm that drop events do work while Chrome is on dev mode, but only if the zoom is 100%. If zoom is less or more than 100%, drop zones seem to get dislocated (at less than 100% drop detection doesn't seem to happen, at more than 100% it seems to happen at the wrong locations)

Comment: which Drag and Drop library are you using? Is it React DnD?

Comment: Hi Caleb, I'm building a custom solution based on HTML Drag and Drop API, no external libraries. But see my edit above, the problem turned out to be dev mode in Chrome, not my code. Solved now.